# XPath comparison of query value to a string

Tags: xml, jakarta-ee, xpath

I am using XPath.I am trying to compare a value which is stored in a string and then writing a query like

```
XPathExpression desc_expr = xpath.compile("/algorithms/info[name=s]/description/text()");
```

where s contains the value and is a string.
I am getting null for this.

However if I write the query like

```
XPathExpression desc_expr = xpath.compile("/algorithms/info[name='somename']/description/text()");
```

then query works.
The string value is of the form abcd_abcd .It has a special character _.Is it because of the special character I get a null value?
Could anyone please help sort this out.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change

```
xpath.compile("/algorithms/info[name=s]/description/text()")
```

to

```
xpath.compile("/algorithms/info[name="+s+"]/description/text()")
```

U need to use string concatenation to have the value in a variable be used.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.But it doesnt work.It still returns empty value.

Comment: Does it not work because the value of the string is something like this abcd_abcd